# 'typeface' or 'font'? Which term is better known to a layman?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm designing a simple CMS in which users (non-experts) can, among other things, choose from a select group of typeface-combinations.

Although not entirely correct ( I believe?) I could also use 'font combination' to explain the feature. What would be the best way to describe the feature to English speaking that are not into typography / design jargon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system allows the user to select the *typeface* (Times New Roman, Courier, etc.), the *weight* (normal, bold, italic, etc), and the *size* (10pt, 11.5pt, etc), then you can both correctly and concisely refer to the process of defining these three options as "font selection", and be widely understood.

Even if your system has some restrictions, such as only supporting one particular weight for a given typeface/size, you can still refer to it as "font selection" since the complete trio of typeface/weight/size is still being determined by the defined process.